# Checkbox input not displaying properly in conjunction with React-Table & React-Window combo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-window

I am trying to combine the [Row Selection](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/row-selection) and [Virtualized Rows](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/virtualized-rows) examples from React-table but the checkboxes don't render properly, the problem is that when you click on them you can see they activate but the tick mark does not appear until you scroll up or down, and the same happens when you deselect the checkbox.

I have a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-window-checkbox-issue-zvszu?file=/src/App.js).

[image]

I think it has to do with the way React-Window updates or re-render the divs but I'm clueless as of how to tackle this problem, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **SelectCheckbox** component props don't update correctly, you must add your **selectedRowIds** as a dependency to your **RenderRow** callback

```
const RenderRow = React.useCallback(
    ({ index, style }) => {
      const row = rows[index];
      prepareRow(row);
      return (
        <div
          {...row.getRowProps({
            style
          })}
          className="tr"
        >
          {row.cells.map((cell) => {
            return (
              <div {...cell.getCellProps()} className="td">
                {cell.render("Cell")}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    },
    [prepareRow, rows, selectedRowIds]
  );
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the functionality of the headers checkbox don't update the others in the table as it should, by clicking the headers checkbox it should be able to select and deselect all from the table, hope that makes sense

Comment: Ok, i found a new way, remove the last changes and just add [prepareRow, rows, selectedRowIds] as your RenderRow callback dependencies

Comment: Mind explaining why that addition to the dependencies made the difference?

Comment: It uses a callback to render your new data and pass it to FixedSizeList, your callback work with some dependencies, when your dependencies are changing your data will update. In this case, you don't pass your selected list as dependency and your data don't know about the changes.

Comment: My pleasure, my friend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235651/discussion-between-erfan-hosseinpoor-and-ricardo-sanchez).